# How much damage does Orbius do with more shifts of effect?

Tags: dresden-files

The book was not specific on this so I kinda got lost. The Orbius example in the book (YS p. 294) uses 3 shifts for effect and 2 shifts for duration. It chokes (Grapples) the enemy and does 1 point of stress per exchange.

If I cast Orbius on an enemy with 8 shifts on effect and 2 shifts on duration how much damage will Orbius do per exchange?

Comment: this is definately something that i'm going to look into when i get home tonight so that i can try and answer all of your questions

Comment: btw, is there a page number in the book that you're getting this from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orbius (p. 294) always does one shift of physical stress each exchange. Changing the number of shifts of effect merely changes the target the victim needs to beat with their Endurance roll. With 8 shifts of power, the victim needs to make an Endurance roll of +8 or better.

Comment: True it does increase the defender's hurdle to beat it but if you read it up to the end page 295. "Variations: The caster could change the power or duration, tailoring it to a given target’s
toughness. A caster could instead use the spell to bind (and damage!) a creature’s legs or hands—in that case, the spell would be a block opposed by Might."

Comment: That still doesn't change how much damage it does. If you want a more powerful crushing effect, a glop of ooze is not the thing to use.

Comment: Hmm you have a point. so if i use the latter? what damage would it give? if i remember correctly super strength give grapples a bonus on the damage. So if i boost the spells power would that be an equivalent of giving the spell super strength?

Comment: One physical stress per exchange, resisted by a Might roll. For *this* spell the power is all about how hard it is to resist. Remember these are just *example* evocations—making your own with the effects you want is half the fun.

Comment: I see. Well I can't make up spells. My DM will always say "you can't do that!!" so our players tailored and limited our characters to what the book has... sigh... so I was kinda hopping for a positive feedback here so i can tell him "see it's not just me who sees it that way." :p Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Your GM needs a kick. It's not DFRPG if you're not making up personalised magic. That's the entire point of the magic system's design.

Comment: @RP21, i agree with SevenSidedDie, the idea that you're supposed to come up with your own spells, just like a real world wizard would.  if you're gm has no creativity... it might be time to get a different one... but that's just my opinion.